# I am given wrapper div height auto but background color and image is not working?

Tags: css

```
<style>
.wrapper{
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#000000;
    position:relative;
    }
.header{
    width:900px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background:#00FFFF;
    }
.body_content{
    width:900px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background:#6666FF;
    }
.fotter{
    width:900px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
    background:#336600;
    }   
</style>
```

---

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="body_content"></div>
<div class="fotter">sss</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you float everything in the wrapper, the browser won't pickup the size of your wrapper div, ie, it consider it has 'zero' height.

Solution:

use the magical overflow keyword in wrapper:

```
.wrapper{
    overflow:auto;
    //...

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I see:
[image]

What are you expecting?

Comment: @sridhar but you didn't write anything to show black color right, i mean any html or css

Comment: once see this css
<style>
body{
 color:red;
 }
.wrapper{
 width:900px;
 height:auto;
 padding:0px;
 margin:auto;
 background:#000000;
 }
.header{
 width:900px;
 height:200px;
 float:left;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 }
.body_content{
 width:900px;
 height:200px;
 float:left;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 }
.fotter{
 width:900px;
 height:150px;
 float:left;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
 } 
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="body_content">Body Content</div>
<div class="fotter">Fotter Content</div>
</div>

Comment: @sridhar , you have header , body content and footer , tell me exactly what do you want to achieve?? might be we are missing something.

Comment: @sridhar , posted the same question agian , tell me clearly what you want , we can easily achieve...it

Comment: before header,body,footer div i'll give one outer div(wrapper). in that div i give one property  is background color black, that color is applying only two divs header and body but its not applying footer div....

Comment: @sridhar , you gave height as auto for the wrapper div , as soon as the footer div ends , i don't think you will be having any extra space...

Comment: If im given wrapper div height:auto; i cont see the background color black. If i am given wrapper div height:550px; then i can see the color.

Answer (score 0):

@sridhar ,

For div the background color should be given like this right

`background-color:#003366` and background image sould be given like this

```
background-image: url(../images/test-background.gif);
```

Comment: I given same (background-color:#003366) but its not working please give me if your any other idea ........

Comment: @sridhar where did you give the above color ,its not there in css...footer is green.