# Background color and image not working with auto outer div height

Tags: css

```
<style>
body{
    color:red;
    }
.wrapper{
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#000000;
    }
.header{
    width:900px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    }
.body_content{
    width:900px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    }
.fotter{
    width:900px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
    }   
</style>    



<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="body_content">Body Content</div>
<div class="fotter">Fotter Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233682/i-am-given-wrapper-div-height-auto-but-background-color-and-image-is-not-working

Comment: I've fixed your post, next time put your html/css inside a code block. I still have not clue what you want though...

Comment: Please do not post duplicates

Comment: You've got some extra CSS in there - `height: auto` is the default and since you want all the inner divs to be the same width as the outer div, you can leave the widths off of them.  In this particular case the floats are also not going to do anything since they inner divs are the same width as their container.  You can leave the px of of 0px, too - the unit's not important when the value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to [clear](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/clear.htm) your floats.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="body_content">Body Content</div>
    <div class="fotter">Fotter Content</div>
    <br style="clear: both;" /> <!-- Google "clear floats" for a few different ways to clear your floats. -->
</div>
```

**[This](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/7NJWS/)** is his problem, and **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/7NJWS/1/)** is his solution.

P.S. It's spelled ***footer*** :)

Comment: what is the problem in his question , i didn't understand the black color at the bottom.